# React mock submit form function using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to create a "simple" test to check if the onSubmit function of the form has been added / not removed from the component. 
Form component:

```
<form onSubmit={SubmitForm} data-test="submit-new-product-form" >
<TextField type="text" ref={enteredNameRef} className="text-field" label="Name" value={enteredName} onChange={event =>  { handleChange('enteredName', setEnteredName, event.target.value) } } data-test="input-entered-name" /></form>
```

Test example:

```js
test('should call submitNewProduct function upon form submission', () => {
  let submitNewProduct = jest.fn(); //This is the mock I'm trying to put to check if it was called  
  let wrapper = shallow(<AddNewProduct />);
  let form = wrapper.find("[data-test='submit-new-product-form']");  

  //This is where things don't make sense to me. Above I have the form component and I need to assign the 
  //submitNewProduct mock function to its onSubmit prop. But I don't know how.
  
  form.simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => console.log('preventDefault') });

  expect(submitNewProduct).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Since your callback isn't getting passed into the component as a prop, you should consider testing a side effect of what the function onSubmit does.

Comment: Hey Possum! I'm kind of intermediate on Javascript, so can you clarify a little more on your answer?